# Cannot create temp dir with proper permission: /mnt1/s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

The following is the log dump of one of the container. I got an exception stating that a folder can't be created due to some permissions. I have troubleshooted various time but still it exist.

> 16/12/19 09:44:05 WARN ConfigurationUtils: Cannot create temp dir with
>   proper permission: /mnt1/s3
>
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /mnt1 at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.t here
>   ranslateToIOException(UnixException.java:84) at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
>   at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674) at
>   java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781) at
>   java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767) at
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.ConfigurationUtils.getTestedTempPaths(ConfigurationUtils.java:224)
>   at
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.initialize(S3NativeFileSystem.java:449)
>   at
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.initialize(EmrFileSystem.java:111)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2717)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:93) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2751)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2733) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:377) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:230)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:201)

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this? We're running into the same problem. See also https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=57967, which looks similar

Comment: I don't have a concrete answer for this. Because this problem got solved automatically when i created a new cluster. For me this was a cluster specific issue. I guess you can compare the all the configuration files of hadoop and yarn . I tried that i found few differences. But its long time ago i don't remember it now

Answer (score 2):

you should use the same instance type for your master and task/core nodes

see: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=57967

Comment: **@Tomer** I'm already using same instance types [`r3.xlarge`] for my `master`, `core` and `task` nodes on `EMR 5.12.0` and still running into this error while running my job [`Spark 2.3.0`] (though only occasionally; i.e., this error appears only sometimes). My `master`, `task` and `core` have these configurations: `8 vCore`, `30.5 GiB` memory, `80 SSD GB` storage, `EBS` Storage: `32 GiB`; with one exception: `task` doesn't have any `EBS` Storage

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when I had an AWS EMR cluster running, and was trying to connect to it from an EMR edge node using RStudio and SparklyR by running a simple "select * from abc" query.

The query worked on the master nodes but not on the edge node. So, I looked at the permissions of /mnt/s3 on the EMR Cluster's master nodes, and compared it with the permissions of that folder in the edge node. The difference was that on the master nodes, the permissions were `rwxrwxrwt` (like that of /tmp), while on the edge node it was `rwxrwxr--`.

When I gave the edge node the same expansive permissions as on the master node, the problem disappeared (I also set the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) so that it is exactly the same as on the master node). The commands I used were.

```
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/s3
sudo chmod o+t /mnt/s3
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem and using different instance types. But my Task nodes have /mnt1/s3 permissions as drwxrwxrwt permission as the master node. I am using Pyspark. I saw the above error in YARN logs. The script continues to run and doesn't halt. So, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for my environment. The master node on emr may have the /mnt1 and /mnt1/s3 directory, but ssh into the worker nodes and they're not configured with the proper directories.

I had to change my setup script from a --Step to a --bootstrap-action in the cluster launch command. This allowed me to pass edits onto all worker nodes, even if they scaled up after the initial cluster launch.